# Prometheus - query to detect the number of pods that existed in the last 24 hours

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I'm still getting to grips with PromQL. I wrote this query in an attempt to detect the number of kubernetes pods that existed in the last 24 hours within a given namespace.

**My process here was:**

- Get the metric filtered to the relevant name-spaces (any airflow ones).
- Get that metric over 24 hours.

  - Each pod will just have lots of duplicates of the same creation time here.
- Use `increase()` to get the range vectors for each pod back into instant vectors.  The value will always be 0 as the creation time  does not increase.
- Now that we have 1 value per pod, use `count()` to see how many existed in that time frame.

```
count(increase(kube_pod_created{namespace=~".*-airflow"}[1d]))
```

Can anyone that knows prometheus well tell me if this logic follows?  Since it isn't a normal database/etc I'm having trouble working out how to validate this query.  It "looks" like it probably does the right thing when expanded out to a day though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58117048/1563297

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend substituting `increase()` with `count_over_time()`, since `increase` may miss short-living pods with lifetime smaller than 2x scrape interval. The following query should return the total number of pods seen during the last 24 hours:

```
count(count_over_time(kube_pod_created{namespace=~".*airflow"}[24h]))
```

Comment: Thanks, that suggestion makes a ton of sense here since airflow schedules thousands of often very-short-lived tasks on kubernetes :).  Question... if a pod lived between 2 scrape intervals, would this metric catch it?  or does the lookup  mechanism only catch pods-live-at-scrape-time?  I wasn't sure if it had any kind of look-back function.

Comment: If the pod lifetime is smaller than the scrape interval, then it may be left unnoticed by Prometheus.

Comment: 24h can be dynamic : $__interval or $_range.. according to your grafana version

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the number of pods that existed in the last 24 hours:

```
count(last_over_time(kube_pod_created[24h]))
```

The `last_over_time(kube_pod_created[24h])` returns time series for pods that existed in the last 24 hours (see [last_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time) docs). The [count()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count) returns the number of such time series, which equals to the number of pods that existed in the last 24 hours.