# prometheus - Not realistic results with count_over_time kube_pod_created and Guage Panel

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

Based on this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63164774/prometheus-query-to-detect-the-number-of-pods-that-existed-in-the-last-24-hour), i implemented a grafana panel as following:

- prometheus query:

```
count(count_over_time(kube_pod_created{cluster="$cluster", namespace="$namespace"}[$__range]))
```

[image]

- Visualization

[image]

I go 56 pods!!
[image]
Unfortunately, the result is not realistic because this k8s namespace just created a while a go and runs only 2 pods

Comment: Trying on my own Prometheus (2.30.3), I confirm the `count_over_time()` does not return the values I was expecting. A workaround could be to use something such as `count(kube_pod_created{namespace="xxx"} > (time() - 3600))` (checking pods starting in the last 3600s => 1h)

Comment: how to link it with the selected period ( $__range ) ? @SYN